How do I fix an oversized XYZ tiles map?
I found a nice historical map on BayernAtlas and wanted to import it into my QGIS project. I got to the point where it displays, but it is way too big. To fix this, I tried a few other projections, like UTM32N and GK4. But the results for those were just as big and - in addition to that - quite distorted. What do I need to do, to get the XYZ tiles layer properly scaled and positioned?
Setup
Layers (XYZ tiles)

https://intergeo38.bayernwolke.de/betty/c_hist/{z}/{x}/{y} (found on https://geoportal.bayern.de/bayernatlas/?bgLayer=historisch and the layer I want to import into QGIS)
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png (the standard OpenStreetMap)

CRS

WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857)

Result


The xyz https://intergeo38.bayernwolke.de/betty/c_hist/{z}/{x}/{y} is not available in EPSG:3857.
At first it looks like they use a local reference system, but it seems they recalculate the x and y values on the web map to show the tiles in the correct place on their map even though the x and y values of the webservice are very low for EPSG:3857. They seem to use the following piece of code to add values to x and y.
tileGridOrigin:JSON.parse("[2420000, 1350000]")

This probably means you can't use this web tile service in any other software.
